# RestKit.h not found - Installed via Cocoapods

Tags: ios, cocoapods

I am calling an import in the PCH file:

```
Prefix.pch....
#import <RestKit.h>


Pod File......
platform :ios, :deployment_target => '7.0'
pod 'RestKit', '~> 0.23.3'
```

It says 'RestKit.h' not found

The pch file contains...:

```
#ifdef __OBJC__
  #import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
  #import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
  #import <SystemConfiguration/SystemConfiguration.h>
  #import <MobileCoreServices/MobileCoreServices.h>
  #import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
  #import <CoreData/CoreData.h>
  #import <RestKit.h>
```

I am running cocoapods 0.37.1, and I verified the 'Link Binary With Libraries' match in the tutorial.

Comment: Did you read the install guide?

Comment: You know, you need to tell us exactly how you installed Cocoapods and how you ran the tool. Otherwise, we can only speculate as to what the problem is.

Comment: Weird.. I moved link_with to the top in the cocoapods and it works now.